# jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'emp_name' cannot be null

Tags: hibernate

I have one table `tbl_employee_payslip`
update function look like

```
  public boolean updatePaySlipData() {

        SessionFactory sf = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();

        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

        s.saveOrUpdate(this);
        tx.commit();
          s.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Table contains `ser(auto incremented primary key) ,emp_name , salary` etc;

I WANT TO UPDATE ONLY `SALARY` AND WRITE CODE LIKE

```
Bean_EmployeeSlip bes=new Bean_EmployeeSlip();

bes.setSerial(ser);

 bes.setEmp_salary(salary);

boolean b= bes.updatePaySlipData();
```

THEN ITS GIVES ERROR LOOK LIKE

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
 Column 'emp_name' cannot be null
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3224)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456)
org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:287)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
Bean.Bean_EmployeeSlip.updatePaySlipData(Bean_EmployeeSlip.java:157)
org.apache.jsp.Admin.Code.UpdateEmpSalaryCode_jsp._jspService(UpdateEmpSalaryCode_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Please Help me....

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the primary key of the entity, why not simply do this:

```
EmployeeSlip employeeSlip = session.find( EmployeeSlip.class, slipId );
employeeSlip.setSalary( salary );
session.update( employeeSlip );
```

Now what you'll notice is that Hibernate will issue an update statement that not only sets the salary but the name attribute too, despite the fact you didn't change it.  That's the default behavior.  You can however use `@DynamicUpdate` so that the update statement only includes the salary for this case given that you didn't modify the name.

Make sure that your entity class also uses optimistic locking here to avoid collisions of updates between multiple sessions on the same row so that you get an `OptimisticLockException` if someone else modifies the entity concurrently.